# How to find the intersection points of two 3D surfaces in Mathematica?

Tags: plot, graph, wolfram-mathematica, intersection, transcendental-equation

I have two equations consisting of two variables and I'm plotting those two functions in 3D by defining the range of the two variables. I need to find the points of intersection of these two functions. I tried using `Graphics'Mesh'FindIntersections` but its not working for 3D plots. Can anyone help me with this? I need to get the data of the intersection points.

The code is as follows:

```
e1= -0.0492101+(0.00982664*l3*Sec[147.557*l3]^2*(Tan[147.557*l8]+3.34665*Tan[152.139*l8]))/(Tan[152.139*l3]*Tan[147.557*l8]-Tan[147.557*l3]*Tan[152.139*l8])+(0.00982664*l8*Sec[147.557*l8]^2*(Cot[147.557*l8]*Tan[147.557*l3]+3.34665*Cot[147.557*l8]*Tan[152.139*l3]))/(-Tan[152.139*l3]+Cot[147.557*l8]*Tan[147.557*l3]*Tan[152.139*l8])==0;
e2= 0.00629091 +(0.113333*l3*Sec[152.139*l3]^2*(Tan[147.557*l8]+3.34665*Tan[152.139*l8]))/(Tan[152.139*l3]*Tan[147.557*l8]-Tan[147.557*l3]*Tan[152.139*l8])+(0.113333*l8*Sec[152.139*l8]^2*(Cot[147.557*l8]*Tan[147.557*l3]+3.34665*Cot[147.557*l8]*Tan[152.139*l3]))/(-Tan[152.139 l3]+Cot[147.557*l8]*Tan[147.557*l3]*Tan[152.139*l8])==0 
plot=Plot3D[{e1,e2}, {l3, 0.008, 0.012}, {l8, 0.008, 0.012}]
```

I have got a 3D plot like this[3d plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9I0B.png). Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try asking here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/